# Multiple Google Webmaster Verification Code on Single Website

Tags: google-search-console, site-verification

I got a website for SEO, But the site is already having a Google verification code. They don't want to share the account details and not giving the account access. So we want to generate a new verification code and add it to the website so that we can track the website details.
But can't remove the existing verification code. So, is this possible can we have the multiple verification codes on a single website?

Comment: What verification method are you using?  Are you manually ain't the verification to your website or is it done with a plug-in like Yoast for WordPress?

Comment: You can add multiple verification codes on the one site.

Answer (score 1):

The Google webmaster verification code for your website & it's subdomains are shared. For example if you verified example.com the same code can and will be used to verify www.example.com

Answer (score 1):

Each person that has site ownership, should have their own verification code via Google Search Console.

Verified owners can delegate ownership to other persons too, however if the verified ownership expires, then the delegated owners lose their access to the Google Search Console Property too
[Verify your site ownership](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35179?hl=en)